# Can you write an update command based on data in multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Like set `smart: true` in `students` where `students.id = reports.student_id` and `reports.grade = 'A'`.

Comment: Nope, can't do that (in one query). Mongodb doesn't have joins.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two queries - an `addToSet` aggregation and `$in` update:

```
db.reports.aggregate([
  {$match: {grade: 'A'}},
  {$group: {_id: '_', res: {$addToSet: '$student_id'}}}
])
```

and then copy the results array to the `$in` clause:

```
db.students.update(
  {id: {$in: [1, 2, 3, 4]}},
  {$set: {smart: true}},
  {multi: true}
);
```